# Kotlin IOS/Android Mutliplatform Hands On tutorial: Unresolved reference: platform

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to learn how to use Kotlin for IOS/Android multiplatform development.

While doing the hands-on tutorial, available here: https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Targeting%20iOS%20and%20Android%20with%20Kotlin%20Multiplatform/03_CreatingSharedCode

I get the error `Unresolved reference: platform` in the file SharedCode/src/iosMain/kotlin/actual.kt:

```
package com.jetbrains.handson.mpp.mobile
import platform.UIKit.UIDevice

actual fun platformName(): String{
    return UIDevice.currentDevice.systemName() +
            " " +
            UIDevice.currentDevice.systemVersion
}
```

Does it only work on MacOS or am I missing something?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

It looks there is a Kotlin runtime/compiler version mismatch in your Android Studio and the project. Make sure you align them with the latest and same version. For example, if the Kotlin plugin in your IDE is 1.3.72, then make sure the kotlin-gradle-plugin in your project Gradle is also using the version 1.3.72.

Answer (score 2):

I have found in the documentation that I need to work on macOS.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/building-mpp-with-gradle.html#using-kotlinnative-targets